# how to use facebook login for an application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, authentication

I am developing an application in which i have to use the facebook or google login for log in my application so please guide to how to use facebook or google  login for login into application and get the some basic information of client

Comment: You are looking for something called 'openauth'. Do a bit of research on that, then get back to SO if you have any questions.

Comment: `developer.google.com` and `developer.facebook.com` and search with `openid` login mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look into oauth.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this where you can use the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk)